# Insert form data in MySql DB using perl

Tags: html, mysql, perl, cgi

I want to insert form data inside a mysql DB using perl.For this i made 2 files,1st is a html file which takes input and 2nd in .cgi file which is called by html file to store the data in a DB using insert query.

The problem I'm facing is that i'm able to take input from user but not being able to insert the values in DB as the cgi file is not being able to take the values from the html file.I also get a syntax error message on form submit..are these 2 related??

HTML code...

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title> Report</title>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;color:white;background-color:blue" Reports</h1>
        <style>

        .label 
            { 
                float: left; 
                width:120px;
                padding:10px 30px;
                <!--font-weight:bold;-->
            }
        textarea
            {
                <!--margin-bottom:90px;
                margin-top:50px";-->
                vertical-align:top;
                overflow : auto;                    
            }
        .textarea
            {
                resize :none;
                border: none;
                width: 100%;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   <!-- <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */-->
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box; <!-- FF1+ -->
                -box-sizing: border-box; <!-- Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1-->
            }
            table.table, th.table, td.table
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            div#box
            {
                border:1px solid black;
                align:center;
                width:250px;
                height:250px;
                padding:10px;
            }
            span#sub
            { 
                display:block; 
                font-weight:bold;
                text-decoration:underline;
                text-align:center;
            }
            label#main 
            {
                <!--display:block;-->
                font-weight:normal;
                margin-bottom:10px;
            }
        textarea#strat 
            {
                border:none;
                width:100%;
                height:65%;
                resize:none;

            }

        </style>
        </head>

<body>
<form action="jaihoshanidevki.cgi" method="post">

<label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
<textarea id="name" rows="1px" cols="20px" style="resize:none" placeholder="Name">sample name</textarea>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="desig" >Designation:</label>
<textarea id="desig" rows="1px" cols="20px" style="resize:none" placeholder="Designation">designation</textarea><br><br><br>

<label for="dept" class="label">Department</label>
<textarea id="dept" rows="2px" cols="20px" style="resize:none" placeholder="Function/Department"> department</textarea>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="date1">Date(YYYY/MM/DD):</label>
<textarea id="date1" rows="1px" cols="14px" style="resize:none" placeholder="Date">2013/05/22</textarea><br><br><br>

<label for="cname" class="label"> Cluster Name</label>
<textarea id="cname" rows="1px" cols="20px" style="resize:none" placeholder="Cluster Name">risk cluster number 1</textarea>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="cnum"> Cluster Number:</label>
<textarea id="cmun" rows="1px" cols="12px" style="resize:none" placeholder="Cluster Number">sample cluster number</textarea><br><br><br>



<p><b>Identification Methodology: (Tick the appropriate option)</b></p>

<input type="checkbox" id="roa"> Already Occured                                   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="roc"> industry:<br><br>              


<label for="date2" class="label">Date of Occurance(DD/MM/YY):</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="date2" rows="1" cols="10" style="resize:none" placeholder="Date">2013/05/22</textarea><br><br><br>

<label for="other" class="label">Others:(Please specify)</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<textarea id="other" rows="2" cols="30" style="resize:none" placeholder="others">sample other</textarea><br><br><br>



<p><b>Preliminary Details(briefly):</b></p>

<label for="desc" class="label">Description</label>
<textarea id="desc" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Risk Description">sample desc</textarea><br><br>

<label for="root" class="label">Root</label> 
<textarea id="root" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Cause">sample root</textarea><br><br>

<label for="rqi" class="label">DQI</label>
<textarea id="rqi" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Description and Qualification">sample DQI</textarea><br><br>



<p><b> Category (Tick the appropriate option) :</b></p> 

<input type="checkbox" id="stra">Strategic                           
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                         
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="roc">Operational                           
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="repu">Reputational

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="comp">Compliance
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <br><br><br>

<div id="box" align="center">
<label for="strat" id="main"><span id="sub" style="text-align:center">Preliminary Risk Mitigation Strategy:</span>(Report in brief, responsibility & next review date)</label> 
<textarea id="strat" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Enter Data" >sample strategy</textarea>
 </div><br><br>

 <input type="submit" id="submit">  <br><br>

                    </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```

.cgi file..

```
  #!/usr/sbin/perl
  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
  use DBI;
  use CGI;
  use CGI::Carp qw (fatalsToBrowser);
  $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=Demo;host=localhost","mint", "MINT123", {'RaiseError' => 1});
  $q = CGI->new;
  $query=CGI->new;
  $name=$query->param('name');
  $desig=$query->param('desig');
  $dept=$query->param('dept');
  $date1=$query->param('date1');
  $cname=$query->param('cname');
  $cnum=$query->param('cnum');
  #$im=$query->param('name');
  $date2=$query->param('date2');
  $other=$query->param('other');
  $desc=$query->param('desc');
  $root=$query->param('root');
  $dqi=$query->param('dqi');
  #$rc=$query->param('name');
  $strat=$query->param('strat');

  #print "$name=====uuuuuu";

 print  $q->header;
 # my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:Demo:localhost";   # Data source name
 # my $username = "mint";                 # User name
 # my $password = "MINT123";              # Password
 # my $dbh,$sth;                          # Database and statement handles
 # $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password);

     $sth = $dbh->prepare("Insert into FIR  (name,desig,dept,date1,cname,cnum,im,date2,other,desc,root,dqi,rc,strat) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     $sth->execute($name,$desig,$dept,$date1,$cname,$cnum,check1,$date2,$other,$desc,
     $root,$dqi,check2,$strat);


                            $sth->finish() or die $DBI::errstr;; 
                            #print "hello";
                            $dbh->disconnect() or die $DBI::errstr;;
```

For checkbox values i'm just trying to put"check1" and "check2" values in the DB that's why i'm not taking parameters for them..

Table structure..

[image]

the table is empty it does not contain any data..

Error message.

[image]

2nd part of error messsage
[image]

3rd part of error message
[image]

Comment: Are you missing your string delimiters around 'check1' and 'check2'? or is this a paste formatting issue? You must have quotes around them...  `$sth->execute($name,$desig,$dept,$date1,$cname,$cnum,"check1",$date2,$other,$desc,
     $root,$dqi,"check2",$strat);'

Comment: yes i did that and put desc as`desc`...it is giving an error message "Column 'name' cannot be null at jaihoshanidevki.cgi line 34."...it's not even taking values from the form...even when i tried taking that particualar form value and storing it in a variable using "param",it's not taking any values from the html form...why???...and I'm even putting sample values inside each text-area so that values are taken and stored in database..

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to quote it with backticks:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("Insert into FIR (... `desc`, ...");
```

Comment: yes i did that...it is giving an error message "Column 'name' cannot be null at jaihoshanidevki.cgi line 34."...it's not even taking values from the form...even when i tried taking that particualar form value and storing it in a variable using "param",it's not taking any values from the html form...why???...and I'm even putting sample values inside each text-area so that values are taken and stored in database..

Comment: What is the value of `$name`? Is it `undef`?

Comment: as you can see in the html code the value of name is"sample name"..i have made it pre-defined just to check whether i'm able to insert values in the DB or not....

Comment: But you're also doing `$q = CGI->new; $query=CGI->new;`, I'm not certain but the first `CGI->new` could be consuming the incoming arguments so that the second one (which you're calling `param` on) could be empty. Don't look at what you think the input is, look at what it actually is. And learn about `use strict;`, `use warnings;`, and `my`.

Comment: i removed the line $q = CGI->new;...added "my" keyword before every arguements and added "use strict;" & "use warnings;"...after doing this i'm getting an error message "Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at jaihoshanidevki.cgi line 36."....ny idea what this means???

Comment: That means that [`prepare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#prepare) returned `undef`, check `$dbh->errstr` and fix the problem.

Comment: i did that..even though the query is being fired,it's only happening once...even when i try to add another row by refreshing the html page and clicking the submit button another row is not being added in the database table..

Comment: You're probably duplicating the `cnum`.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler is saying you have sql syntax error, in your program, there is a syntax error.

your query :

```
Insert into FIR  (name,desig,dept,date1,cname,cnum,im,date2,other,desc,root,dqi,rc,strat) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

There should be no space between table name and the bracket.so the correct query is:

```
Insert into FIR(name,desig,dept,date1,cname,cnum,im,date2,other,desc,root,dqi,rc,strat) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

I think this would help you..